# Como pegar o texto de um botão?

Tags: java, android

É assim, tenho um jogo de perguntas e respostas. Em que cada questão tem 4 respostas (colocadas nos rótulos de botões).
Como faço para pegar o texto do botão clicado para comparar com uma String?

Comment: Usando Java????

Comment: Usando Java sim!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você primeiro deve buscar o elemento do XML,

```
 final Button btnResposta1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnResposta1);
 final Button btnResposta2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnResposta2);
```

depois implementar o onClickListener

```
private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //faca um cast para Button
            Button botao = (Button)view;
            //pegue o texto
            String respostaBotao = botao .getText().toString();
            switch (view.getId()){
                case (R.id.btnResposta1):
                    //codigo caso clicar resposta 1
                    break;
                case (R.id.btnResposta2):
                    //codigo caso clicar resposta 2
                    break;
        }
}
```

associar depois ao listener dos botões.

```
btnResposta1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
btnResposta2.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

espero ter ajudado!